# How can I make the widget ignore paddings? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I have

```
  SafeArea(  
      minimum: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 0),  
      child: Column(  
        children: [  
          //some widgets
          Expanded(  
            child: CupertinoScrollbar(  
              child: ListView(  
                children: [  
                  CarouselSlider(...),
                  //some widgets that need paddings
```

And CarouselSlider has horizontal paddings defined in the SafeArea. How can I make the CarouselSlider ignore paddings without Transform.scale?
P.S. ignore paddings only for CarouselSlider

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
Expanded(  
        child: CupertinoScrollbar(  
          child: ListView(  
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: [  
              CarouselSlider(...
```

Comment: paddings do not disappear

Answer (score 0):

Remove the minimum atribute, then set each one with its own padding.

Comment: it is possible, but I think there is some more beautiful solution